# Regular expression replace string in project

Tags: regex

I am trying to replace a string in project... which has a common pattern

```
    sometext instanceof somevar ==false
    abc instanceof   alphabet   ==false
    xyz instanceof   demo  ==false
```

expected behaviour :

```
!(xyz instanceof   demo)
!(abc instanceof   alphabet)
```

I am trying to replace the string but wasnt able to..can you please help me out....

The steps i tried is  `*.instance0f\s((.*))` 
 i am able to get the whole text but then i am not sure how do i replace it with the expected behaviour i want ... i tried using $1 but its replacing the same text.

Comment: Why `instance\s+0f` when `instanceof` is one word and doesn't contain a zero

Comment: What kind of project? Does it consist of multiple files, or what? What implementation of regex are you using, and what are you using to replace the strings?

Comment: its a java project ... i am trying to replace file using eclipse ...i am trying to replace string with its substring......

Comment: @jsheeran i accidentally added the \s for the instanceof ..... edited my code...

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/ohBlpc/1

Comment: You can't do this with one regex, if I properly understand your requirement.  You  will need to list all the possible abc, xyz,...etc values and write a regex for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
find: ([^\s]*)\s*instanceof\s*([^\s]*)\s*==\s*false
replace: !($1 instanceof $2)
```

You can try it at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WEeeN4/1/).

Comment: which one is for finding and which one is for replacing ?

Comment: @user9302609 Please mark this as answer if it solved your problem

Comment: You should see an outline of a checkmark next to the answer. Just click on it.